# Scala regex + partial function unapply performance

Tags: regex, scala, partialfunction

Assume that I have a code like:

```
val pf: PartialFunction[String, Unit] =
  "string" match { case regex(g1, g2, _*) =>
    function(g1, g2)
  }
```

`pf` has methods `isDefinedAt` and `apply`. Will the regex search be evaluated once, in `isDefinedAt` point, or the job will be done twice?

If once, how args `g1, g2` get passed to `apply` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex will be evaluated once. The work is done in the extractor, `Regex.unapplySeq`. The extractor's return type is `Option[List[String]]` so it knows whether the regex was a match (either `Some` or `None`) and the captured groups (the `List[String]`) all in one bundle.

Comment: But how captured groups appear in apply method? So, the code above should be translated in new PartialFunction { def apply ... ; def isDefinedAt ... }. Could you please show how would these methods look like?